# Disguising tall exhaust stacks

Tags: structures, building-design, architecture

While architectural features are oftentimes more aesthetic than they are technically complex, this still seemed like a suitable question for here.

I am working on a project for an industrial type facility that will include one or more large exhaust air stacks. These stacks are part of an odor control system, so while the air will be clean, the final step is to get the air high over the area for the purposes of dispersion. 
The facility will be in a relatively nice part of town so the residents don't really want to see the stack. Are there proven ways to hide such a structure or to make it more appealing similar to what is done with cell towers disguised to look like trees?

Comment: Paint them to match the background ... Don't put them in a "nice" part of town - relocate the plant... Or light them up with a laser display, lots of possibilities : local info, pictures etc etc

Comment: Be prepared to have some very long arguments with your country's aviation regulatory body.

Comment: What air flows are we talking, to get an idea of the size of your stack? Or do you allready know the size?

Answer (score 1):

> Disguising tall exhaust stacks - The facility will be in a relatively nice part of town so the residents don't really want to see the stack. Are there proven ways to hide such a structure or to make it more appealing similar to what is done with cell towers disguised to look like trees?

It is possible to make them look like trees but without branches and foliage they'll be a couple of sticks. [You can't make a silk purse out of a sow's ear](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/can-t-make-a-silk-purse-out-of-a-sow-s-ear), but I have a workaround.

Another possibility is brick, or build an artistic structure around them to make them an attraction instead of an eyesore. It depends on the height and the budget.

[image: Cover up the stacks]

Companies like [Trashpresso](https://trashpresso.com/trash-tech/) make tiles from waste plastic, part of the beautification of tower can be accomplished by using recycled materials; good for the environment and the view.

[image: TrashPresso Tile]

Answer (score 0):

You will have buildings wih ventilation, with exhaust air vents on the roof (usually). Duct your air from the odour control system there. Worst case you will need a slightly bigger blower.

Comment: The need for the exhaust is a foregone conclusion. I was looking for ways to make the neighbors a little happier about it

Comment: And do you have sizing information?

Comment: It wasn't really a question of size.  The site sits in a lower spot, topographically, and we need a tall stack for proper dispersion so that any odors that remain after the odor control system are not making the surrounding area stinky.  By the same token, I don't want it to look like just a big pipe with guidewires because people tend to start complaining about property values, etc...

Comment: sizing refers to air flow. makes a difference between a DN300 pipe and a 2m x 2m duct. But this info belongs into the question.